# Issue with crash in TKinter Application

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I have a program running that is having issues when the timer runs. Every time "start" is hit, the application crashes. Any thoughts?

```
##-- Imports --##

import time
import openpyxl as xl
from Tkinter import *

##-- Classes --##

class App(Frame):

    def startTimer(self):
        self.check = True
        self.now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        while self.check == True:
            self.timer.configure(text = self.now)
            time.sleep(1)

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Emma's Time Manager")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    def initWidget(self):

        ##Create button definitions##
        self.buttonwidth = 12
        self.quit = Button(self, text = "Quit", comman = self.quit, width = self.buttonwidth)
        self.newClient = Button(self, text = "Add Client", command = lambda:self.newClientFunc(), width = self.buttonwidth)
        self.timeStart = Button(self, text = "Start", command = lambda:self.startTimer(), width = self.buttonwidth)
        self.timeEnd = Button(self, text = "End", command = lambda:self.endTimer(), width = self.buttonwidth)
        self.saveBut = Button(self, text = "Save", command = lambda:self.saveFunc(), width = self.buttonwidth)
        self.viewClient = Button(self, text = "View Client", command = lambda:self.viewCliFunc(), width = self.buttonwidth)


        ##Create lable definitions##
        self.timer = Label(self, text = "00:00:00") ##self.timer used as display for timer##

        ##Create the listbox for Client Selection##
        self.wb = xl.load_workbook("clients.xlsx")
        self.clientNames = self.wb.get_sheet_names()
        self.clivar = StringVar(self)
        self.clivar.set(self.clientNames[0])
        self.clilist = apply(OptionMenu, (self, self.clivar) + tuple(self.clientNames))

        ##Create Entry Box to describe work information##
        self.info = Entry(self, width = 50)


        ##Create GUI for widgets##
        self.clilist.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.timer.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.timeStart.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.timeEnd.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        self.info.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
        self.newClient.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.viewClient.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.saveBut.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        self.quit.grid(row = 2, column = 3)


    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "light blue")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
        self.initWidget()

def main():
    try:
        xl.load_workbook("clients.xlsx")
    except:
        temp = xl.Workbook()
        temp.save("clients.xlsx")
        temp.remove_sheet(temp.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet"))

    root = Tk()     
    bob = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Please note that most of the program is not yet finished. I just cannot seem to get this timer to run properly.

Comment: How does it "crash"? Do you get an error message? Does the app freeze? Something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley By crash I mean that it just freezes, then after a few seconds windows says that it needs to close.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, that's why it freezes. While you are sleeping, and while you're in the loop, `mainloop` is unable to process any events, including system events such as redrawing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no way out of your `while` loop.  You'll either need to set `self.check` to `False`, or `break` out of the loop.

```
while self.check == True:
    self.timer.configure(text = self.now)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Aye, but that would not cause a freeze in most settings.

Comment: @NoahPotvin: If you won't return the control to the event loop then it does freeze the gui (there is a single thread. `time.sleep(1)` does not yields control. Here's a [proper way to create a loop in tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/74f62de8a4d99e4e9c399808c6e004e1).